# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\bigg(x^2\bigg(1+2+3+\ldots+\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\mid x\mid}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)\bigg)$

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\bigg(x^2\bigg(1+2+3+\ldots+\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\mid x\mid}\bigg\rfloor\bigg)\bigg)$

I could not attempt this problem at all. All it seemed like a sum upto $\infty$. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what happens for the sequence $x=1/n$? What happens for $x=1/n^2$. Any conclusions from these cases?

Comment: This is basically a twist of Riemann sum of $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes,@BrianM.Scott made me realise that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=x^2\left(1+2+3+\ldots+\left\lfloor\frac1{|x|}\right\rfloor\right)\;.$$

Suppose that $\frac1{n+1}<|x|\le\frac1n$, where $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $n\le\frac1{|x|}<n+1$, so $\left\lfloor\frac1{|x|}\right\rfloor=n$, and

$$f(x)=x^2\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12n(n+1)x^2\;,$$

where $$\frac1{(n+1)^2}<x^2\le\frac1{n^2}\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Yes, I can finish from here. Limit as a sum...thank you. It was nice.

Comment: @Swadhin: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The expression inside the limit is $$f(x)=x^2\left(\frac{k(x)(k(x)+1)}{2}\right)$$ where $k(x)=\lfloor1/|x| \rfloor\le 1/|x| $ Thus $$0\le f(x)\le \frac{|x|+1}{2}$$  Can you start from here?